# How to order adjacent posts (prev / next) by custom field value?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, navigation, sort

I am using the [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) and [More Types](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/) plugins to create a custom post type called `product`. This custom type is based on the **Post** type.

One of the fields is named `lot` which is an integer representing a Lot # for an auction.

I created a custom category page which generates a list of links for each Lot, ordered by the `lot` field. This works great.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array('product'), 
  'cat' => 3,
  'meta_key' => 'lot',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

**However...** when you click on one of the lots, the Previous & Next post links aren't ordered by the `lot` field anymore, they are ordered by publish date (which is the WP default).  I am trying to figure out how I can change this default sort order for `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` to use custom field `lot` instead of Publish date.

Answer (score 5):

You can filter SQL to change to your condition in [`get_adjacent_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1039) ) :

```
$sort  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_sort", "ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1" );
```

Or filter link altogether in `adjacent_post_link()` ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1370) ) :

```
echo apply_filters( "{$adjacent}_post_link", $format, $link );
```

PS `$adjacent` can be `next` or `previous`.

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond it's included in SQL query, passed through the filter. Might not be very convenient, but nothing overly complex to get it from there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but the upvoted answer by @Rarst is not clear to me! Does that mean that I need to tweak the code in the `link-template.php` file?

Comment: @EmKarimifar there is no need to edit core code, because the relevant part can be filtered, however you would need to modify a raw SQL to what you need, which isn't trivial.